# my website not working on iPhone google chrome

Tags: google-chrome

my website not working on iPhone google chrome
am using wordpress and  Elementor Pro so when i deactivate elementor pro plugin
my website shows on iPhone without any scrolling down
i contacted elementor support and they said ...
Upon inspecting the source code of your website, I noticed the following error:

- TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '/Version/([0-9]+)/.exec(navigator.userAgent)[1]')

Coming from:

jQuery( window ).load(function() {

// Check if user agent is Safari and version is less than 14 (macOS 11 Big Sur)
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') != -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') == -1 && parseInt(/Version/([0-9]+)/.exec(navigator.userAgent)[1]) < 14) {
// User is using Safari browser previous versions than macOS 11 Big Sur
// Do something...
alert("You are using an unsupported Mac OS or safari browser for better performance please change your browser to chrome or firefox");
}

I believe this function is part of your custom code Footer Script. Can you please try to unpublish this custom code (set its status to Draft), clear the server cache, and check the website preview?

I did that but nothing happened
I also tried to rollback elementor version but it doesn't work too.